# Bigquery - browsing table data on table of type view

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to use the preview/head feature of BigQuery to see sample data of a table without charge
as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#preview-data), and to do so i tried using the python api listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-data#browse-table)

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to browse data rows.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

# Download all rows from a table.
rows_iter = client.list_rows(table_id)  # Make an API request.

# Iterate over rows to make the API requests to fetch row data.
rows = list(rows_iter)
```

which results in:

`BadRequest: 400 GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/your-project/datasets/your_dataset/tables/your_table_name/data?formatOptions.useInt64Timestamp=True&prettyPrint=false: Cannot list a table of type VIEW.`

Is there a way to preview a table of type view?

Is there another free alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the TableDataList JSON API method(the API you are using here) to retrieve data from a view. This is [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro#view_limitations) of view. So, only way is to use the original table to preview the data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you could write the contents of the view into a temp table and link to that instead. Not the cleanest solution I'd agree on that.

drftr